# unable to redraw the path on android

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am trying to redraw the path covered on a view when a button is clicked.
For this I have maintained a linked list of all the points covered by the touch event.But unfortunately nothing is draw on canvas.
I have checked all the flows of control through print statements and they seemed to work fine.
Please help me figure it out

The code in touch event is:
x,y are event.getx(),event.gety() respectively

```
    switch(event.getAction()){
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        path.moveTo(x, y);
        return true;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        path.lineTo(x, y);          
            ll.add(new Point((int) x, (int) y));
        break;
    default:
        return false;
```

The event handler for button is

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            setPractise = true;
            path.reset();
            postInvalidate();   
        }
```

The ondraw method is

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if(!setPractise){
    canvas.drawPath(path, pencil);
    }

    else
    {       
        while(( p =ll.getNext()) != null){
            x = (float)p.x;
            y = (float)p.y;
            canvas.drawLine(px, py, x, y, pencil);
            System.out.println("working"+"x is "+x+" y is "+y); 
            px =x;
            py = y;

        }
    }
}
```

[image: The screen shot of present view]

Comment: Why dont you draw it with a path?

Comment: Its like I want to draw small circles on equidistant points on my path. so I had to try a linked list

Comment: What is with your pencil? Have you tried to draw a lone from for instance x=0 to x=100?

Comment: ontouch succesfully draws. Problem only with button onclick

Comment: The clicklistener and the if clause are working correctly?

Comment: And you see your log output?

Comment: yeah the logcat shows all the prints I have pasted in respective flows of control

Comment: Also able to manually retrace the paths that are drawn because of ontouch listener through logcat outputs in ll.getnext()

Answer (score 0):

Try to call first the super method in your onDraw method:

```
super.onDraw(canvas);
```

Comment: And can you give the layout/canvas some background to see if the measurement/dimensions are correctly working? Thanks

Comment: No . same behavior is exhibited

Comment: Ok then please try to colorize the background and draw a simple line to see if you can draw something on the canvas.

Comment: Any way its a custom view generated dynamically. But, I have tried a canvas.drawcircle(..) before entering the while loop in else clause of ondraw. It works. But the while loop things do not work

Comment: Ok I understand but here is another easy solution. Instead of saving the points in an arraylist, make a second path and save it for practising. Then you can reset the touch path and can draw the practisepath and everything is working great. Deal? :)

Comment: And if you want to draw small circles its also possible. Make a for-loop over the path points and draw your circles on the points.

Comment: will give it try. But I ought to find that out

Comment: hi tomweber, looks like the path idea works... but just not able to understand why my previous thing did not work..

Comment: Honestly, I dont understand too. It's a kind of confusing but when this works everything is great. I think the easist way to draw your circles is to aave the points in your list again and then draw the circles with the saved points.

Comment: @tomweber In case you are following the thread please help me with  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28000023/drawrect-does-not-work-on-android-4-4-2-but-works-on-5-1